# MissingMethodException when creating an object with reflection

Tags: c#, object, reflection, missingmethodexception

I'm using reflection to create objects coming from an external assembly. My problem is that I cannot create an object that way:

```
Type t = assembly.GetType("ExternalClass");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[] { data, Type.Missing, Type.Missing });
```

I get System.MissingMethodException: `Additional information: Constructor on type 'ExternalClass' not found.` However everything works fine using that way:

```
Type t = assembly.GetType("ExternalClass");
ConstructorInfo[] constructors = t.GetConstructors();
object obj = constructors[0].Invoke(new object[] { data, Type.Missing, Type.Missing });
```

`ExternalClass` has only 1 constructor with 2 optional parameters and I'm sure I'm passing correct arguments, because the second way creates the object I want. Do I miss something in the first approach? I would prefer the first one, because it's easier to read

EDIT:
I forgot about `CultureInfo` (why would this method need it?!). The solution is to use:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t,
    BindingFlags.CreateInstance |
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, null, new object[] { data, Type.Missing, Type.Missing }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Does your ExternalClass provides public ctor, seems not?

Comment: `constructors[0].IsPublic` gives me True, it is indeed

Comment: How should I invoke `CreateInstance` using `BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding`? Maybe that's the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way how you should construct the constructor with the `Activator`

```
(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 
    BindingFlags.CreateInstance |
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, null, new object[] { data, Type.Missing, Type.Missing }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Great! That worked, thank you! Btw, I still wonder, why would `CreateInstance` need `CultureInfo`...

Comment: Good question can be next question on stackoverflow is still doesn't exist, I could not find the real usage...

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding the appropriate [binding flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx), for example:

```
(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 
                BindingFlags.CreateInstance |
                BindingFlags.Public |
                BindingFlags.Instance | 
                BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
                null,
                new object[] {data, Type.Missing, Type.Missing },
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: nope, I still get `Constructor on type 'ExternalClass' not found.` with that approach

Comment: Strange thing is, that despite copying your code, Visual Studio gives me the previous overload tip when I point cursor at the method - why can't I see the BindingGlags in its parameters? [link](https://i.imgur.com/CuGvaS5.png)

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at the overloads, it also takes a culture, I'll edit the snippet